# An alternative proof of the Tietze Extension Theorem(s)

Tags: general-topology, alternative-proof

Last summer I was working through a lot of Topology. I made it through the sections of my notes that dealt with separation properties, covering properties and continuous functions between spaces without too much difficulty. Then I came to Urysohn's Lemma, which was incredibly challenging to figure out. I only succeeded due to a very helpful lemma that my notes encouraged me to prove before attempting to prove Urysohn's Lemma. I then moved on to Tietze's Extension Theorems (there were two in my notes). I wasn't able to figure out how to prove this without help, so I finally read a proof of the Theorem.

https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Tietze_Extension_Theorem

I was shocked to find that the proof invoked the use of a uniformly continuous function and used a converging geometric series to wrap up the proof. It is a brilliant move, and I never would have thought of it on my own.

My question is: Is there a more (set) algebraic proof of The Tietze Extension Theorem(s) that anybody knows of or could write? I felt that the proof relied a lot on analysis, and at the time my mind was very algebra-oriented.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a proof that uses a more sophisticated version of the ideas used in the usual proof of the Uryson lemma. You can find it in my old paper ‘A “More Topological” Proof of the Tietze-Urysohn Theorem’, *The American Mathematical Monthly*, Vol. $85$, No. $3$ (Mar., $1978$), pp. $192$-$193$,.

Comment: Thank you; that is more along the lines of what I am after. "Glorified Calculus" is a great way to describe the other proof I read!

Comment: @graydad: You’re welcome. Yes, I have to admit that although it’s very slick, I’ve never found the usual proof very appealing.